# Calculating percentage using PIG latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table with two columns (code:chararray, sp:double)

I want to calculate the percentage of every sp.

```
INPUT
t001 60
a002 75
a003 34
bb04 56
bbc5 23
cc2c 45
ddc5 45
```

desired OUTPUT:

```
code Perc
t001 17%
a002 22%
a003 10%
bb04 16.5%
bbc5 6%
cc2c 13.3%
ddc5 13.3%
```

I tried like this but output is not coming.

```
A = load '....' as (code : chararray, sp : double); 
B = GROUP A BY (code); 
allcount = FOREACH B GENERATE SUM(A.speed) as total; 
perc = FOREACH A GENERATE code,speed/(double)allcount.total * 100; 
dump perc;
```

---

How can i do using pig latin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the second column into a field called sp but referring to it as speed.I presume that the columns are separated by a single while space,if it is a tab then use PigStorage('\t') in the LOAD statement.

```
A = LOAD '/YourFilePath/YourFile.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (code:chararray, sp:double); 
B = GROUP A ALL; 
C = FOREACH B GENERATE SUM(A.sp) AS total; 
D = FOREACH A GENERATE code,ROUND_TO((sp/(double)C.total) * 100,2) AS perc;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE code,CONCAT((chararray)perc,'%'); 
DUMP E;
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks man for your reply. But still I am getting the error. sp and speed both are same. I dont know if it version issue.  I am getting the error like  after using dump D; because giving error for the last statement too.  2016-07-14 18:25:08,642 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias D. Backend error : org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (61.0), 2nd :(64.0) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar" should be "foo::bar" )

Comment: I am using  Apache Pig version 0.15.0.2.3.2.0-2950 (rexported)

Comment: @sandy The group by is incorrect.I've corrected it.Try now.Since all the rows in column 1 have unique values,you will have to group by ALL to get the sum.

Comment: Thanks @ inquisitive_mind. But still I am getting the error. Actually i am trying in grunt shell. After using GROUP ALL, I am getting following error: 2016-07-14 20:52:15,668 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 4, column 18>  mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN

Comment: @sandy just copy and paste

Comment: A = LOAD 'Sandy/input_test/test1.csv' using PigStorage(',') As (code:chararray,sp:double);
B = GROUP A BY all; 
C = FOREACH B GENERATE SUM(A.sp) AS total; 
D = FOREACH A GENERATE code,(sp/(double)C.total) * 100 AS perc;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE code,CONCAT(perc,'%'); -- Concat perc with '%' to get desired output format.
DUMP E;

Comment: I am getting the following error:                                                            2016-07-14 21:55:17,689 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file speedbin.pig, line 2, column 18>  mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN

Comment: that is incorrect,see the script I have given,can't you even copy what I have posted? I have even executed the script and posted the output.

Comment: It look silly but when I compiled with above given dataset, it executed with one warning and output came, as desired. But when I am running the code with bigger datasets. Its executing but no result and giving some VERTEX error. I am guessing its because of warning message of casting to DOUBLE.  can you see @ inquisitive_mind after compiling 4th Line one warning is coming.