# Calculating Percentage and casting using PIG latin

Tags: apache-pig

I have a table with two columns (code:chararray, sp:double)

I want to calculate the percentage of every sp.

INPUT

```
t001 60.0
a002 75.0
a003 34.0
bb04 56.0
bbc5 23.0
cc2c 45.0
ddc5 45.0
```

desired OUTPUT:

```
code Perc
t001 17%
a002 22%
a003 10%
bb04 16.5%
bbc5 6%
cc2c 13.3%
ddc5 13.3%
```

Here @inquisitive_mind has given the good suggestion and I was able to get the above output. see [Calculating percentage using PIG latin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383412/calculating-percentage-using-pig-latin/38384578#38384578)

```
A = LOAD '/YourFilePath/YourFile.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (code:chararray, sp:double); 
B = GROUP A ALL; 
C = FOREACH B GENERATE SUM(A.sp) AS total; 
D = FOREACH A GENERATE code,ROUND_TO((sp/(double)C.total) * 100,2) AS perc;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE code,CONCAT((chararray)perc,'%'); 
DUMP E;
```

But when i am running with bigger dataset. Output is coming but the second field is coming as 0. See sample output:

```
    at001 0%
    a102 0%
    a203 0%
    bc04 0%
    bbc5 0%
    c42c 0%
    d6c5 0%
```

How can i get the correct output with bigger database or is there suggestion in above code using pig latin?

Comment: Tip: Do the concatenate and the percent calculation in the same line to avoid another map-reduce job

Comment: Also, in your linked answer, the output was not 0, so I don't understand the problem. Are you sure your input file is correct?

Comment: yes I am using correct input. Its working fine with smaller dataset. But when i am using big size its showing 0 in the second field.

Comment: Probably because you are summing so many number that you are getting an Integer overflow and there is nothing you can really do about that

Comment: Its around 208766 lines. I don;t thing its too much. I am getting the warning  message after fourth statement for the casting. so probably this might be the reason.

Comment: See what `DUMP C` gives you. You should cast the total in that `C` line before you calculate the percent.

Comment: After DUMP C; Its giving 8546556 and I tried using sp/8546556 * 100. The perc field is again coming zero.

Comment: NOW I am getting the second field output as                              2.106111514392464E-6)
4.44623541927298E-6)                                                                                                             After removing the ROUND_TO function. But again I want upto 2 digits after decimal. Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about this for a second...

What is `60.0/8546556`? A really small number... Something that, as you can see that is so small that it requires a `E -6`.

So your code is working correct because it rounds 0.000007 to two decimal places and shows 0.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the awesome discussion @cricket_007.